# How to run a downloaded asp.net C# project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I feel ridiculous for asking this because it seems like it should be so simple, however I have been unable to discover an answer to this question.

I have a free standing set of files of asp.net with C#. I don't know how to import them into Visual Studio 2013

So how do you add existing projects and files in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Did it come with a .sln or .csproj file?